# Django admin model add page save button not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to add a model from the admin page and when I press save the model doesn't add and nothing happens, the button darkens and that's as far as it goes.

By the way, the admin page save doesn't work for either one of the models, nor Actualite, nor Message

Here's my models.py

```py
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

# Create your models here.

class Actualite(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    miniature = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/thumbnails')
    contenu = HTMLField()
    date_creee = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date créée", auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    date_modifiee = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Modifiée", auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.titre} | {self.auteur} | {self.date_creee}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_modifiee']
        verbose_name = "Actualité"

class Message(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    contenu = models.TextField()
    date_recu = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nom} | {self.date_recu}"
```

and settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for jac project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os.path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-+1j_(+ad1&!9_0+r+u1d&6pieo5q$zv%c-*$vykrx8lnk8c244'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jac.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jac.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "theme": "silver",
    "height": 500,
    "content_css": "/static/tiny.css",
    "images_upload_url": '/upload',
    "menubar": True,
    "plugins": "advlist,autolink,lists,link,image,charmap,print,preview,anchor,"
    "searchreplace,visualblocks,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,paste,"
    "code,help,wordcount",
    "toolbar": "undo redo | image | formatselect | "
    "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter "
    "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | "
    "removeformat | help",
}
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "tinymce")
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Actualite, Message

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Actualite)
admin.site.register(Message)
```

ps: the problem is with the admin page because when i save a model from the python shell it works and also appears on the admin page

Comment: You'll have to include your `admin.py` as I'm guessing the problem is in there ...

Comment: as requested i added the admin.py code but that shouldn't be the issue because i didn't make any changes and just registered the models with the django admin default register function

Comment: I see you have an `HTMLField` where does that come from? (Note: some of these WYSIWYG editors replace the content of the form field when the submit button is pressed, this can result in weird situations because the browsers form validation thinks the field is empty but problem is that it isn't filled by the JS yet)

Comment: the ```HTMLField``` comes from the TinyMCE rich text editor downloaded via ```pip install dajngo-tinymce```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form stopped saving to database after TextField was changed to HTMLField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662092/form-stopped-saving-to-database-after-textfield-was-changed-to-htmlfield)

Comment: no not really because that fixes the issue when used in a form but i am using the admin page without a special form so i wouldn't know how to implement that

Comment: I specified in the question that regardless of tinymce the add functionality doesn't work, regardless of the model